# Uable to run migration on heroku on a postgre database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, rails-migrations

I need to add a property/column to a table in a production database(Postgre) on Heroku.com (Rails app) by doing migration.
When I do the migration it looks ok, but when I view the columns on the table it has has not added the column!

My development db is sqlite3 and the production db is postgre

I do the following:

```
heroku run rails generate migration AddUtc_OffsetToEvents utc_offset:integer RAILS_ENV=production --app app-name-1111
```

and it returns:

```
invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20130304070946_add_utc_offset_to_events.rb
```

And then I run the migration

```
heroku run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --app app-name-1111
```

And then:

```
heroku restart
```

When I run

```
heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL --app app-name-1111
```

and check the columns of the table:

```
\d+ events
```

It still does not have the utc_offset column, and no errors are displyed while doing the previous cmds.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: What are the contents of the migration file?  And why are you creating migrations in production?  You should be doing that in dev first.

Comment: Content of migration: `class AddUtcOffsetToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :events, :utc_offset, :integer
  end
end ` This is necessary as the migration done in dev was not added to version control by mistake before deploying to heroku

Comment: Can you try without `RAILS_ENV=production`? That may be screwing up the Toolbelt when it parses the command. `RAILS_ENV=production` will be automatic in this case anyway. `heroku run rake db:migrate --app app-name-1111`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are doing several calls to `heroku run`

Each time you do `heroku run` it spins up a completely new dyno with your latest code, and when run is over that dyno is destroyed. So the second heroku run does not have the migration filed created in the first.

Since you are already familiar with psql you can just use `ALTER TABLE` directly. Otherwise you'll need to check your migration into your code and `git push heroku master` it to heroku, *then* run it.

Comment: Checked the migration into heroku and then ran the migration - thanks Will

Answer (score 0):

Why not just download the code, add the migration and push the changes ?
After, just run the heroku run rake db:migrate on the app.